# read file and append each line to another file with tabs and spaces

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

file_name="webproxy.conf"
echo "#generated code" > $file_name
while read line
do
    eval echo $line >> $file_name
done < "./template.txt"
```

template.txt:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header  blabla ;
    }
}
```

the output in `webproxy.conf`:

```
server {
listen 80;
location / {
proxy_set_header  blabla ;
}
}
```

How can I add the missing spaces in order to prettify the result file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to format the file at the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{sub(/^[ \t]+/,"");idx=0}
/\{/{ctx++;idx=1}
/\}/{ctx--}
{id="";for(i=idx;i<ctx;i++)id=sprintf("%s%s", id, "\t");printf "%s%s\n", id, $0}
```

Demo:

```
#cat c
server {
listen 80;
location / {
proxy_set_header  blabla ;
}
}

# cat c | ./ngainx_fmt
server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header  blabla ;
        }
}
```

Where `ngainx_fmt` is the `awk` script

Answer (score 0):

It easiest to use `awk` for a task like this.

`$0 ~ /{/` searches for an opening brace and sets the indent.

`$0 ~ /}/` searches for closing brace and reduces the indent.

`{ print dent $0 }` prints the line, prefixed with the indent.

**Spaces indent version**

```
file_name="webproxy.conf"
echo "#generated code" > $file_name

awk 'BEGIN { dent="";nspaces=3}
{ print dent $0 }
$0 ~ /{/ {for (n=0; n<nspaces;n++) dent=dent" "}
$0 ~ /}/ {dent=substr(dent, 0, length(dent)-nspaces)}
' template.txt >> $file_name
```

**Tabs indented version:**

```
file_name="webproxy.conf"
echo "#generated code" > $file_name

awk 'BEGIN { dent=""}
{ print dent $0 }
$0 ~ /{/ {dent=dent"\t"}
$0 ~ /}/ {dent=substr(dent, 0, length(dent)-1)}
' template.txt >> $file_name
```